# How Do I incremental number for each new entry in SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, team-sites, title-column

I want the title column to have an incremental number for each new entry how do I do that. [image]

Comment: If you are only need a column with auto-number field just modify the view and add ID column

Answer (score 1):

in SharePoint every list item have a property called `Id`. Which is always incremental. You can use it to solve your problem using below method:

1. Create a workflow, set it to run on `Item created`.
2. In workflow, add statement `set field in current item`.
3. In the first item select the desired field i.e. `Title` field.
4. In value section click on value and then click on button having `...` value. Now the string builder will open up. Add the Title column and ID column separated by `-`.

Thats it, your work is done. WF looks like following.

[image]